LlamaIndex + Gemini issue using structured data
When i run the below code i get the below error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/navdeepparmar/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/embeddings/utils.py", line 59, in resolve_embed_model
validate_openai_api_key(embed_model.api_key)
File "/Users/navdeepparmar/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/embeddings/openai/utils.py", line 104, in validate_openai_api_key
raise ValueError(MISSING_API_KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE)
ValueError: No API key found for OpenAI.
Please set either the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable or openai.api_key prior to initialization.
API keys can be found or created at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/navdeepparmar/Documents/python/Llama/Llamaindex.py", line 22, in 
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
File "/Users/navdeepparmar/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/indices/base.py", line 145, in from_documents
return cls(
File "/Users/navdeepparmar/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/indices/vector_store/base.py", line 71, in init
else embed_model_from_settings_or_context(Settings, service_context)
File "/Users/navdeepparmar/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/settings.py", line 274, in embed_model_from_settings_or_context
return settings.embed_model
File "/Users/navdeepparmar/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/settings.py", line 67, in embed_model
self._embed_model = resolve_embed_model("default")
File "/Users/navdeepparmar/opt/anaconda3/envs/dev/lib/python3.10/site-packages/llama_index/core/embeddings/utils.py", line 66, in resolve_embed_model
raise ValueError(
ValueError:

Could not load OpenAI embedding model. If you intended to use OpenAI, please check your OPENAI_API_KEY.
Original error:
No API key found for OpenAI.
Please set either the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable or openai.api_key prior to initialization.
API keys can be found or created at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys
Consider using embed_model='local'.
Visit our documentation for more embedding options: https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/module_guides/models/embeddings.html#modules

This is my code
import os
GOOGLE_API_KEY = "abcd"  # add your GOOGLE API key here
os.environ["GOOGLE_API_KEY"] = GOOGLE_API_KEY

from llama_index.core import SimpleDirectoryReader, VectorStoreIndex, Settings
from llama_index.llms.gemini import Gemini

Settings.llm = Gemini(model="models/gemini-pro")

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader("./data").load_data()
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
query_engine = index.as_query_engine()

response = query_engine.query("which fruit is Green in color?")
print(response)


My data is {"fruit": "Apple","size": "Large","color": "Red"}
{"fruit": "Orange","size": "Small","color": "Orange"}
{"fruit": "Pomegrenate","size": "Large","color": "Red"}
{"fruit": "Banana","size": "Medium","color": "Yellow"}
{"fruit": "Pears","size": "Medium","color": "Green"}

to insert the documents into the vectorstore, llamaindex needs to use a component that generates embeddings. By default, OpenAI embeddings api is used. This is where your code fails, because it does not find an env variable with the OpenAI api credentials. You need to check on how to plug in a different embeddings component. For example, hugging face transformers can also be used:
from llama_index.embeddings.huggingface import HuggingFaceEmbedding
from llama_index.core import Settings

Settings.embed_model = HuggingFaceEmbedding(model_name="BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5")

https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/module_guides/models/embeddings/
